# conditional statement stop and run 2 coroutine unity

Tags: unity

[image]
The scenario will look like this: IE 1 will spawn the enemy, until the player kills the enemy and has enough points, IE 1 will stop and run IE 2. IE 2 runs spawn coin after 10s IE 2 stops and IE 1 continues to run
how can i get such script,sorry  my bad. 
many thank....

Comment: It looks like you should work your way through more introductory Unity and C# tutorials. You won't get far in game development asking folks to write your game code for you. We're happy to help you along the way if you run into a specific problem making your solution work, but you should always start by trying to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain execution from one `IEnumerator` to another by `yield`ing it. So we can have one master coroutine that expresses the eternal alternation between these two phases:

```
IEnumerator AlternatingSpawnLoop() {
    // Keep looping forever.
    while(true) {
        // Run the enemy spawn loop until the enemy phase is over.
        yield return EnemySpawnLoop();
        // Run the coin spawn loop until the coin phase is over.
        yield return CoinSpawnLoop();
        // Repeat.
    }
}
```

Then write an `IEnumerator` for each phase to handle its own logic:

```
public float enemySpawnInterval = 5f;
public int scoreIncrement = 100;

IEnumerator EnemySpawnLoop() {
    int scoreGoal = ScoreManager.GetLocalPlayerScore() + scoreIncrement;

    // Keep looping until we reach or exceed 100 points from the start of the wave.
    while(ScoreManager.GetLocalPlayerScore() < scoreGoal) {
        // Spawn another enemy, then wait.
        SpawnManager.SpawnEnemy();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(enemySpawnInterval);
    }
}

public float coinSpawnInterval = 1f;
public int coinsToSpawn = 10;

IEnumerator CoinSpawnLoop() {
    // Spawn a controlled number of coins in total (helpful for balancing)
    for(int i = 0; i < coinsToSpawn; i++) {
        // Spawn a coin, then wait.
        SpawnManager.SpawnCoin();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(coinSpawnInterval);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save the coroutine when you start it if you want to stop it later on. You can do this with:

```
IEnumerator myCoroutine = StartCoroutine(firstIE);
```

So, later on you can simply do:

```
StopCoroutine(myCoroutine);
```

So what you have to do is firstly save the initial coroutine when you call it and then modify the conditional statements appropriately.

[More info](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) on StopCoroutine